# I want to write generic validation that i can use in any angular form - normal reactive is already done and working fine

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular8

I want to write generic validation that i can use in any angular form - normal reactive is already done and working fine.Can anyone please resolve this problem.

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
  import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

// import custom validator to validate that password and confirm password fields match
   import { MustMatch } from './_helpers/must-match.validator';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'val';

      registerForm: FormGroup;
        submitted = false;
        constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
        ngOnInit() {
          this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
              title: ['', Validators.required],
              firstName: ['', Validators.required],
              lastName: ['', Validators.required],
              email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
              password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
              confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required],
              acceptTerms: [false, Validators.requiredTrue]
          }, {
              validator: MustMatch('password', 'confirmPassword')
          });
      }

      get f() { return this.registerForm.controls; }

      onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;

        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }

        // display form values on success
        alert('SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n' + JSON.stringify(this.registerForm.value, null, 4));
    }

    onReset() {
      this.submitted = false;
      this.registerForm.reset();
    }
    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <div class="card m-3">
      <h5 class="card-header">Form Validation</h5>
      <div class="card-body">
          <form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
              <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col">
                      <label>Title</label>
                      <select formControlName="title" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.title.errors }">
                          <option value=""></option>
                          <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                          <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                          <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                          <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                      </select>
                      <div *ngIf="submitted && f.title.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                          <div *ngIf="f.title.errors.required">Title is required</div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-5">
                      <label>First Name</label>
                      <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.firstName.errors }" />
                      <div *ngIf="submitted && f.firstName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                          <div *ngIf="f.firstName.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-5">
                      <label>Last Name</label>
                      <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.lastName.errors }" />
                      <div *ngIf="submitted && f.lastName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                          <div *ngIf="f.lastName.errors.required">Last Name is required</div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Email</label>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="email" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.email.errors }" />
                  <div *ngIf="submitted && f.email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                      <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
                      <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.email">Email must be a valid email address</div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col">
                      <label>Password</label>
                      <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }" />
                      <div *ngIf="submitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                          <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
                          <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.minlength">Password must be at least 6 characters</div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col">
                      <label>Confirm Password</label>
                      <input type="password" formControlName="confirmPassword" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.confirmPassword.errors }" />
                      <div *ngIf="submitted && f.confirmPassword.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                          <div *ngIf="f.confirmPassword.errors.required">Confirm Password is required</div>
                          <div *ngIf="f.confirmPassword.errors.mustMatch">Passwords must match</div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group form-check">
                  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="acceptTerms" id="acceptTerms" class="form-check-input" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.acceptTerms.errors }" />
                  <label for="acceptTerms" class="form-check-label">Accept Terms & Conditions</label>
                  <div *ngIf="submitted && f.acceptTerms.errors" class="invalid-feedback">Accept Ts & Cs is required</div>
              </div>
              <div class="text-center">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary mr-1">Register</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="reset" (click)="onReset()">Cancel</button>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what would this "generic validator" do?

Comment: Generic validation that i can use in every form of my application like right now this only one form of application if suppose i have 10 forms in the application i can import the validation as directive and use it in ' N ' number of forms.

Comment: okay, but still the question remains, what should this validator do? Validators can do different things. But if you for example want to compare two values, then just pass the formcontrols to the validator, which does the check. So there you have a "generic" validator.

Comment: BTW, seems you already have a "generic" validator, as you pass the formcontrolnames to your custom validator, so I don't know what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

so, you can do custom validation using AbstractControl

url.validator.ts:

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function ValidateUrl(control: AbstractControl) {
  if (!control.value.startsWith('https') || !control.value.includes('.io')) {
    return { validUrl: true };
  }
  return null;
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ValidateUrl } from './validators/url.validator';

@Component({
  // ...
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      userName: ['', Validators.required],
      websiteUrl: ['', [Validators.required, ValidateUrl]],
    });
  }
}
```

for more info check the **link** : [alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-custom-validator](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-custom-validator/)

Comment: Hello Safwan, Thanks it working for me but one more thing i want to know - how to add patterns in this... I want to use pattern that allows only alphabets not numerics e.g ----- pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*"

Comment: how i can check user enter only alphabets not numerics
url.validator.ts
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

const alphabetic = '[a-zA-Z ]*'
export function ValidateEmail(control: AbstractControl) {
    if (!control.value.alphabetic) {
      return { validEmail: true };
    }
    return null;
}
-
form.html

<div class="form-group">
<label>Email</label><input type="text" formControlName="email" class="form-control"/>
<div *ngIf="submitted && myForm.get('email').errors && myForm.get('email').errors.validEmail">Email is required</div></div>
app.component.ts

Comment: Firstly,  you can access the entered data using the control attribute (control.value) .

Comment: Then,  to validate the entered data,  you can use regex, and by passing your pattern to that regex as an attribute you will achieve your goal

Comment: hi Nick, alright I will give you 2 lines of code, in the first line I created a new instance of regex (regular expression) to check if the entered string is compatible with or not, and in the second line I applied regex so this will return true if and only if matches our pattern                                                              
 let regex = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z]+$') 
 console.log(regex.test(control.value));

Comment: I hope you learn more about regex and understand the entered pattern and I will give you a good tutorial link: 
https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/regular-expressions-the-last-guide-6800283ac034

Comment: Hello Safwan, Thanks ...I am using in console code in "IF" condition it's working fine in my code..... e.g ------ if (!regex.test(control.value)) { // code }